# Find closing tag in PHP using strpos

Tags: php, escaping, strpos

I'm doing a cURL request and retrieving the document as a string. Now I would like to find a specific word, if it exist I echo:

```
if (strpos($response,"word") !== false) {
echo 'word exists';
}
```

This works good but now I need to find the closing body tag, so I do:

```
if (strpos($response,"</body>") !== false) {
echo 'body exists';
}
```

This fails to work as expected (blank screen). I tried escaping but without succes. Is this problem related to escaping or is there something else going on?

Comment: This should work just fine. Please show us the output from the source code: `var_dump($response);`

Comment: It writes string(5340) " and then it just displays the entire website: http://rosalieruardy.nl/

Comment: The code should work fine, or the website doesn't contain `</body>`. Also check your source code for the output.

Comment: var_dump($response) too. and check manually for </body>

Comment: Show us the code that populates `$response`.

Comment: @sebastianForsberg The code is for an app Im developing. I cant show the code (secret company info) but it involves multi-curl request and the output actually comes straight from the server buffer. I dont know if that makes a difference because if I check the type of $response then I get "string" so its definitely a php string

Comment: Is `</body>` in the string? or try `echo 'body exists';
} else { echo 'closing body not found';}`.